# How to modify groups of a grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'A': [*'1112222'], 'B': [*'abcdefg'], 'C': [*'ABCDEFG']})
```

that is like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   A
1   1   b   B
2   1   c   C
3   2   d   D
4   2   e   E
5   2   f   F
6   2   g   G
```

I want to do a groupby like this:

```
groups = s.groupby("A")
```

for example, the group 2 is:

```
g2 = groups.get_group("2")
```

that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C
3   2   d   D
4   2   e   E
5   2   f   F
6   2   g   G
```

Anyway, I want to do some operation in each group.

Let me show how my final result should be:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   b   B   a=b;A=B
2   1   c   C   a=c;A=C
4   2   e   E   d=e;D=E
5   2   f   F   d=f;F=F
6   2   g   G   d=g;D=G
```

Actually, I am dropping the first row in each group but combining it with the other rows of the group to create column C

### Any idea how to do this?

Summary of what I want to do in two lines:
I want to do a group by and in each group, I want to drop the first row. I also want to add a column to the whole dataframe that is based on the rows of the group

---

**What I have tried:**

In order to solve this, I am going to create a function:

```
def func(g):
    first_row_of_group = g.iloc[0]
    g = g.iloc[1:]
    g["C"] = g.apply(lambda row: ";".join([f'{a}={b}' for a, b in zip(row, first_row_of_group)]))
    return g
```

Then I am going to do this:

```
groups.apply(lambda g: func(g))
```

Comment: The logic is unclear, you should provide a step by step explanation

Comment: I think I got it, you meant you're dropping the first **group**, not row. Don't have much time now but I'll try to answer later if no one does in the meantime

Comment: No. The first line of each group

Comment: Its still not clear. Can you summarize in 2 lines what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your expected output -> `1=2;a=b` what is this in column C?

Comment: `I also want to add a column to the whole dataframe that is based on the rows of the group` what do you mean by this, can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes its basically the first group, how does that relate to column C

Comment: what happens if there is another row in your original df. `9  4  j`. With this as the last row, what does your final output look like?

Comment: what happens if there is another row in your original df. 9  4  j. There is no such situation. I am going clean it in advance

Comment: is this a string? `1=2;a=b`?

Comment: please check now

Comment: After the change it is totally different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a custom function to each group where you add the elements from the first row to the remaining rows and remove it:

```
def remove_first(x):
    first = x.iloc[0]
    x = x.iloc[1:]
    x['D'] = first['B'] + '=' + x['B'] + ';' + first['C'] + '=' + x['C']
   # an equivalent operation
   # x['D'] = first.iloc[1] + '=' + x.iloc[:,1] + ';' + first.iloc[2] + '=' + x.iloc[:,2]
    return x

s = s.groupby('A').apply(remove_first).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C        D
1  1  b  B  a=b;A=B
2  1  c  C  a=c;A=C
4  2  e  E  d=e;D=E
5  2  f  F  d=f;D=F
6  2  g  G  d=g;D=G
```

Note: The dataframe shown in your question is constructed from

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'A': [*'1112222'], 'B': [*'abcdefg'], 'C': [*'ABCDEFG']})
```

but you give a different one as raw input.